# Display image without shape pyqt

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

I am trying to create a pyqt application which contains three windows.

1. Display video stream from camera as BGR format using QPixmap and opencv.
2. Display Masked image using QPixmap and opencv.
3. Display screen grab using PIL library, opencv and QPixmap.

The error that I face while displaying masked & screen grab frame is given below.

```
screen_grab_height, screen_grab_width, screen_grab_channel = image_grab_frame.shape ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

When I checked the frame.shape I found that it has only two values, i.e. image_height and image_width. It does not have image_channel value.

I am attaching the code for both the functions below,

1. **Masked image**

```
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_hue, upper_hue)
mask1=cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
hsv_height, hsv_width, hsv_channel = hsv_image.shape
hsv_step = hsv_channel * hsv_width
mask_height, mask_width, mask_channel = mask_frame.shape
mask_step = mask_channel * mask_width
convertToQFormat = QImage(mask_frame.data, mask_frame.shape[1], mask_frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
pic = convertToQFormat.scaled(1280, 720, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
self.normal_screen.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(pic))
```

and

2. **screen grab**

```
screen_grab_height, screen_grab_width, screen_grab_channel = image_grab_frame.shape
screen_grab_step = screen_grab_channel * screen_grab_width

#Display image grab#
convertToQFormat = QImage(image_grab_frame.data,image_grab_frame.shape[1], image_grab_frame.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
image_grab_pic = convertToQFormat.scaled(1280, 720, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)     

self.normal_screen.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image_grab_pic))
```

Comment: Change your loss into one of categorical cross entropies. BCE is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options :-

1. `loss="binary_crossentropy"` is correct as you only have 1 class. Earlier due to it being unclear about the number of classes, I did a mistake there.
2. change the model and the rest is the same.:-

```
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
```

3. `DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE= (256, 256)`
4. In this section

```
try:
        image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
        if image is not None:
            image = cv2.resize(image, DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE)   
            return img_to_array(image)
        else:
            pass
```

If you had "None" images then you have to filter them out at first and you can just a simple `pass`.
5) I am not sure why you are changing the mode to `channels_first` but that would make the channels at `0` index and here it should be

```
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=0))
```

In fact, just don't change the `K.image_data_format()` and then you won't even need to pass the `axis` in `BatchNormalization`.

Comment: I had tried the above said method but I'm still facing the same issue. Adding to the same I have a small query. Here `DEFAULT_IMAGE_SIZE = tuple((256, 256))` but my image in the dataset is 2448 x 3264.

Comment: @user13973948 How many classes do you have? As for the size of the image, it won't matter as you are resizing your image.

Comment: @user13973948 I have no idea about your current error.